# Connecting to Hive 2.3.0 using JDBC

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

First off, I want to apologize if this question turns out to be redundant.
I did thoroughly research this site and the web in general before posting, to no avail. There is just so many different suggestions of which I have tried many and none of them worked out for me.
I am trying to write a java program which would connect to Hive 2.3.0 in a remote cluster but keep getting an error.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at CreateDB.main(CreateDB.java:12)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc:hive://##########:####/default
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at CreateDB.main(CreateDB.java:20)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at CreateDB.main(CreateDB.java:27)
```

I am using the code from [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_quick_guide.htm) example on TutorialsPoint website (the "Create Database" example)
I have included:
    hive-exec-0.8.1.jar
    hive-jdbc-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar
    hive-jdbc-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78-sources.jar
    hadoop-common-2.4.0.jar
in my build path, but it didn't solve the problem.

Thank you all in advance for any help that might be offered.

Comment: Find a JAR named `hive-jdbc-standalone*.jar` in a version that is close to, but not higher than, the version of your HiveServer2. With a stress on **standalone**.

Comment: Basically, search your Hadoop Edge Node for the Hive client install...

Comment: Or, download the Cloudera driver (based on Simba SDK, way better than the lame Apache driver on many respects) and adapt the URL.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am trying to do exactly what you said right now. Trying to download the "standalone" jar from hortonworks repo website but for some reason the download will not start! I think it might have something to do with my computer. It's my work machine. Protected piece of Windows driven crap. Won't let me download or install anything without having to raise a request.

Comment: If you have an HDP 3.1.0 cluster, you probably shouldn't be using `hadoop-common-2.4.0` library

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use a mavenized project rather a simple java project. Your pom must have the following jars.

Also refer the github example [link](https://github.com/rajeshbalamohan/jdbc_hive_standalone_program/blob/master/pom.xml)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0-mr1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks man. I'll give it a try. I am not familiar with Maven but it has been on my to do list for some time now.

Comment: Except for those Hive 1.1 versions won't work for Hive2 connections, and you don't need the metastore or service just for JDBC

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I am still trying to make it work but I suspect that I just need more info about the cluster to be able to connect.Things like, which transport mode it uses, whether it uses Zookeeper or Knox, etc. I originally got access to this cluster from my course instructor but now the course is over and even though he promised to keep the cluster running for some time so that we can practice, he stopped replying to emails and there is no way for me to find out any of those things. I think I'll just create my own cluster on aws and work with that.